# AspectJ and calling another method in @AfterReturning method

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, aspect

I'm starting to learn how to use AspectJ in Spring. I have the following class. I want to perform first method in new thread (long running task), so I thought this might be achieved using Aspect - when firstMethod is called, Aspect automatically delegate this calling into new Thread. After firstMethod is finished, secondMethod should be called with returned by firstMethod value as an argument.

```
public class SimpleClass{
    public Object firstMethod(){
        //some operations
        return object;
    }
    public void secondMethod(Object returnedObjectByFirstMethod){
    }
}

@Aspect
public class SimpleAspect {

   @Around("execution(* SimpleClass.firstMethod(..))")
   public void doInNewThread(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
       Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
           public void run() { 
               joinPoint.proceed();
           }
       });
       t.start();
   }

   @AfterReturning(
      pointcut = "execution(* SimpleClass.firstMethod(..))",
      returning= "result")
   public void doAfter(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object result) {
       SimpleClass.secondMethod(result);
   }
}
```

This is kind of prototype, I haven't implemeneted it yet, I'm pretty sure it cannot work that way, but I want to make sure about two trivial things:

1. How can I call secondMethod() in doAfter(), if this method would not be static? Do I need kind of an instance of SimpleClass is SimpleAspect? How to supply such instance?
2. Nearly the same as first question, but what if secondMethod() would not be in the same class as firstMethod()?

Comment: One comments about what you do: Why do you want to have two threads to simulate a normal (one thread) behaviour?

Comment: There is only one thread - in doInNewThread method, where do you see second?

Comment: In this thread there is performing firstMethod, which is long running task, and the result of this method must be processed in secondMethod. To be more specific, secondMethod must be done on EDT, I want to have kind of equivalent of SwingWorker.

Comment: there are two threads in your description of what you want to do: "I want to perform first method in new thread (long running task) and after it finish, run second method with returned value as an argument." -- Thread A) the one that already exists, Thread B) the one that you creates.

Comment: @Ralph I updated my question, now it should be more clear.